# Passing array data to a variable in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables

How do I pass the contents of the `$the_slug` to the `$post_name` variable in the loop?

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
foreach ($tags as $tag){

global $post;
$the_slug = $tag->slug; //contains 10ish words that associate with my permalinks: welcome, home, about, contact, etc

$post_id = 'welcome';
$post_name = $the_slug; //fails to populate here
$queried_post = get_post($post_name); //if changed to $post_id works but only 'welcome' post
$excerpt = $queried_post->post_excerpt;
$excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
$excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $excerpt);
echo $excerpt . "\n\n";
}
```

Thanx for looking.

Comment: We need a bit more info here. Is `$tag->slug` an array or a string?  What does `get_post` function look like?

Comment: The first parameter for get_post has to be a Post ID or post object. I’d say, this is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979837/wordpress-query-single-post-by-slug

Comment: $tag->slug contains strings: welcome, home, about, contact, etc...$get_posts = get_posts($tag->slug);...get_posts is a wordpress array that contains meta:  [ID], [post_content], [post_title], [post_excerpt], [post_status], [comment_status], etc... I'm trying to get my tag descriptions to pull in post excerpts of the same name/slug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the array with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($the_slug as $slug){
   $post_name = $slug;
   $queried_post = get_post($post_name); $excerpt = $queried_post->post_excerpt;
   $excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $excerpt);
   $excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $excerpt);
   echo $excerpt . "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot closer to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm getting an "invalid argument supplied for foreach()" which points to my array, I think. The dumped array contains 10 strings which should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: could you post here the result of:  var_dump($the_slug) ?

Comment: $the_slug = $tag->slug;   var_dump ($the_slug);    string(7) "welcome"    string(4) "home"    string(5) "about"    string(7) "contact"...... I know it's something about looping through the array but I'm struggling to see what. The tags are showing and I can pull in the excerpt for the post I am on but not for posts that are linked to my tags. I thought I should be able to use a variable to add to the foreach loop.

Comment: it doesn't say $the_slug is an array, it should read like array(3){[0]=> string(7) "welcome" [1]=>string(4) "home" [2]=>string(5) "about" [3]=>string(7) "contact"}   Have you pasted the entire output?

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanx. Think I need to re-write my function. I was under the impression the variable was an array as it was cycling through different posts in the foreach loop. Thanx again.

Comment: glad to help you, remember to mark the answer if this solved your problem, so it can help others